# redis key expire show -1 even it is set to 900 seconds

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

From past few days, I am facing this issue on live.

I am maintaining a key in REDIS and each time system setting key in redis, It also set expire in it.

But few days back, User start saying that system behaving different. After some search, I found redis key expire set to -1. But this is not coming on test server.

I am insert this same key from website and from game.
Can anyone tell me, What is going on(I think concurrency issue)?

Comment: Are both game and web setting the expiry? Are you using SET or SETEX? Any chance you can run  a MONITOR in production? You need to provide more information to get help

Comment: @MagdKudama we are using SET and from both end we are setting expire 900 seconds